# Not to show the external I.P address in viewing in mobile

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I created subdomain in go daddy account, and I pointed to i.p address of GCE google cloud computing engine.

In DNS Management, I click add button

type = A
host = nameofsubdomain //
point to = i.p address
ttl = 1 hourd //default

in forwarding under subdomain section, I click add button

subdomain = mysubdomain

forward to = htt://i.p address

forward type = 301 (permanent)

settings = forward only

when I tried in url, at first it works fine the name of subdomain is visible in url, after couple of hour or minuetes? when I tried again in url my subdomain will turn into i.p address. how to show name of subdomain I don't want to show i.p addresss.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically asked for it to be forwarded to a URL containing the IP address. If that's not what you want, undo it.

Comment: Your configuration is not what you said you want, although it's what you said you did.